# Equation of chord of a parabola whose midpoint is given

Tags: conic-sections

How to prove 
$$ T = S1 
$$ $$ i.e  \qquad yy_1 - 2a(x+x_1) = y_1^2 - 4ax_1=0$$
as the equation of chord for a parabola y$^2$ = 4ax whose midpoint (x$_1,y_1$) is given.

$$$$
I couldn't understand how the equation of chord, can be the same as the equation of tangent at $ (x_1,y_1$) i.e $yy_1 - 2a(x+x_1)=0$. Again since there is a tangent at 
(x$_1,y_1$) that mean we have a parabola inside. If it is so, how we have same focus (a,0) for both the parabola.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You made a typo here.  It should be
$$
yy_1-2a(x+x_1)=y_1^2-4ax_1
$$
without the $=0$ at the end.  The point $(x_1,y_1)$ does *not* lie on the parabola $y^2=4ax$.  Instead, it is tangent to a shifted parabola $y^2-4ax=y_1^2-4ax_1$ in order to be the midpoint of a chord.  The foci of this shifted parabola is $(a+x_1-y^2/(4a),0)$.

Let's get back to proving the equation of chord.  Suppose $(as^2,2as)$ and $(at^2, 2at)$ are two points on the parabola $y^2=4ax$.  The mid-point of the chord is
$$
\left(a\frac{s^2+t^2}{2},a(s+t)\right)=:(x_1,y_1)
$$
and the equation of chord is
$$
\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{2a(t-s)}{a(t^2-s^2)}=\frac{2a}{a(t+s)}=\frac{2a}{y_1}.
$$
So
$$
yy_1-y_1^2=2a(x-x_1),
$$
or equivalently
$$
yy_1-2a(x+x_1)=y_1^2-4ax_1,
$$
as claimed.