# What is the midpoint of the chord of contact form a point $P(4,5)$ to the curve $3x^2+4y^2=1?$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, curves

My method is to find the equation of the chord wrt to the point $P$ and the midpoint, say  $O(\alpha,\beta)$ and then compare them.

Equation of the the chord wrt to $P$ is$^1$:
$$T=0 \text{ where } T=12x+20y-1.$$

So the equation of the chord is: $$12x+20y-1=0\tag1$$

The equation of the chord wrt to $O$ is$^2$

$$T^{'}=S_1 \text{ where } T^{'}=3\alpha x+4\beta y-1 \text{ and } S_1=3\alpha^2+4\beta ^2-1. $$

So the equation of the chord is: $$3\alpha x+4\beta y-1-3\alpha^2-4\beta ^2+1=0\tag2$$

Now since $(1) \text{ and } (2) $ are equations of same line then they are equivalent then we have on comparing $$ O(\alpha,\beta)=O(4,5). $$

Which is wrong and absurd, but why? There seems to be no mistake in this method. The answer is $O(\frac{1}{37},\frac{5}{148}).$

---

The diagram of the question is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eDzh.png).

1: $T=0$ is true for all conics, and hence for [circles](https://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-coordinate-geometry/chord-of-contact.aspx) as well.

2: $T=S_1$ is true for all conic curves in general, but I found this shown [online](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249671/equation-of-chord-of-a-parabola-whose-midpoint-is-given) for parabolas only.

Comment: You don't show calculations. There must be errors in them. I get right answer on comparison.

Comment: Please send me the image. You can use imugar to send image.

Comment: This is not that kind of site. Kindly show your work, so we can point out mistakes.

Comment: You're right it was a typo. But I think I have shown my work in the post.

Comment: As to calculations in my method there is no need of heavy calculations but apparently my method is wrong.

Comment: On substituting (4, 5) in eq 2, one gets $12x+20y=148$. Please show/check your calculations of getting (4, 5).

Comment: You seem to have obtained the wrong chord equation... Ask yourself, does $12x + 20y - 1$ pass through $P(4, 5)$ ?

Comment: You're right that the chord doesn't pass through P. But then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chord of contact obtained from $T=0$ for $(4,5)$ is $$3x \cdot 4 + 4y \cdot 5=1$$
and from $T=S_1$ for $(\alpha, \beta)$ is
$$3x \cdot \alpha+4y \cdot \beta=3\alpha^2+4\beta^2$$

Their coefficients must be proportional, so
$$\frac{\alpha}{4}=\frac{\beta}{5}=\frac{3\alpha^2+4\beta^2}{1}$$

From first two of these simultaneous equations, $\beta = \frac{5}{4}\alpha$. Using this with first and third,
$$\frac{\alpha}{4}=3\alpha^2+4\left( \frac{5}{4}\alpha \right)^2 \Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{1}{37}$$

Hence $(\alpha, \beta) = (\frac{1}{37},\frac{5}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{37})=(\frac{1}{37},\frac{5}{148})$.

Thus the method used by comparing $T=0$ and $T=S_1$ is completely correct.

Comment: What a dumb mistake it was!

Comment: Thank you and happy holidays.

Answer (score 1):

It is appropriate to consider the chord of contact of
$$3x^2+4y^2=1 \tag*{(1)} $$

from $P(4,5)$, which is
$$12x+20y=1 \tag*{(2)} $$
Then we can find their intersection by solving (1) and (2).

Elimination yields
$$
3\left(\frac{1-20 y}{12}\right)^{2}+4 y^{2}=1
$$
$$y=-\frac{1}{4} \text{ or } \frac{47}{148} $$
Putting back to (2) yields the corresponding values of
$$x=\frac{1}{2} \text{ and }-\frac{33}{74}  $$
Therefore the mid-point of contact is $$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{33}{74}\right), \frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{47}{148}\right)\right)= \left(\frac{1}{37}, \frac{5}{148}\right).
$$
Diagram for reference:
[image]

Comment: Your answer is correct. But my main question was why my method is not working. I should have clarified that in the post. Thank you.

Comment: I don’t understand your equation (2)1

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249671/equation-of-chord-of-a-parabola-whose-midpoint-is-given This answer proves this theorm for parabola but can be genralsied for all conic curves.

Comment: O, lying inside the ellipse, has no chord of contact! O only lies on the equation (1).

Comment: By chord of contact of the ellipse from $P$, I mean the chord which passes through the point of contact of the tangents to the ellipse from $P.$

Comment: $O$ is the mid point of the chord. And satisfies both the equations (1) and (2).